# How to determine if a raster has rowattributes?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

I have a raster file which is the result of extract by mask geoprocessing tool. If it has no rows then I take it as no overlap between input raster and shapefile. Following is the way I am reading it to determine whether a row exists or not. But it gives me zero answer even if a row exists. Please help me to better control this process.

```
    a = 0
    grid1 = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask("iras",fc)
    grid1.save(optfolder + '/oras')
    arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(optfolder + '/oras',"Overwrite")
    grid2 = arcpy.SearchCursor(optfolder + '/oras',"","","Count","")
    rows = grid2.next()
    if rows == None:
        count = 0
        a = a + count
    else:
        count = rows.getValue("Count")
        a = a + count

    del rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would structure the code like this:

```
  a = 0
  grid1 = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask("iras",fc)
  grid1.save(optfolder + '/oras')
  arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management(optfolder + '/oras',"Overwrite")
  rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(optfolder + '/oras',"","","Count","")
  for row in rows:
    if row is None:
        count = 0
        a += count
    else:
        count = row.getValue("Count")
        a += count

  del rows
```

If you are using ArcMap 10.1 or above, the following code makes use of the faster [data access module for cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000):

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(optfolder + '/oras', "Count") as rows:
  for row in rows:
    if row[0] is None:
        count = 0
        a += count
    else:
        count = row[0]
        a += count
```

For anyone interested in reading about `x == None` vs `x is None`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none) is a SO link that links to a great blogpost [here](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html).

Implementing @NathanW's great suggestion below:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(optfolder + '/oras', "Count") as rows:
      for row in rows:
        a += row[0] or 0
```

Comment: How much faster is `arcpy.da` vs the old method?

Comment: @NathanW, according to [this](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit12/papers/introducing_the_arcpy_data_access_module.pdf) (page 5), search cursors can be up to 30x faster. Speed aside, the support for `with` statements and (generally!) avoiding improper closing alone is a great reason.

Comment: You could also do this https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/7065041 which removes the if but does still does the null check.

Comment: @NathanW, had to play around with it to understand what was going on, but that is really neat!